# Django 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'filter'

Tags: python, django

**The task:** To assign a single user to the model at a time.

**The Error:**

> Django 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'filter'

The **models.py** is

```
class Post(models.Model):
    post_tag = models.ForeignKey(ProjectUser, related_name="user_tag", blank=True, null=True,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Where **ProjectUser** is:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser

class ProjectUser(AbstractUser):

    def __str__(self):
        return self.username
```

The **.html** code is :

```
% for post_user in objects %}
<form method='POST' action="{% url 'a_tag' post_user.id %}">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <input type='hidden'>
    {% if post_user.id in assigned_user %}
        <button type='submit'>Cancel</button>
    {% else %}
        <button type='submit'>Start</button>
    {% endif %}
</form>
```

The **urls.py** is

```
path('<int:tag>', views.tag_analyst, name='a_tag'),
```

The **views.py** function is **<-** **`Filter`, `add` and `remove` attributes here are causing the errors**

```
def tag_analyst(request, tag):
    post = get_object_or_404(Post, id=tag)

    if request.method == 'POST':
        if post.post_tag.filter(id=request.user.id).exists():
            post.post_tag.remove(request.user)

        else:
            post.post_tag.add(request.user)

    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('homepage'))
```

The views.py class

```
class View(LoginRequiredMixin, ListView):
    context_object_name = "objects"
    model = Post
    template_name = "page.html"

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['assigned_user'] = self.request.user.user_tag.values_list('id', flat=True)
        return context
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`post_tag` is a `ForeignKey` field for `Post`, so `post.post_tag` is an object (or `None` in this case), but not a `Manager`. So you can't `filter()`.

You can just check `if post.post_tag`. This will be `True` if a user is associated, and `False` (`None`) if not.

Comment: I changed it to `if request.method == 'POST':
    if post.post_tag:
        post.post_tag = False

    else:
        post.post_tag=True`
I need that html button to change the status of that field whether there is a user asssigned to it or not. I get `Cannot assign "True": "Post.post_tag" must be a "ProjectUser" instance.`

Comment: You can set it to `None` or to `request.user`. As I said, `post.post_tag` is a `ProjectUser` object or `None`.

Comment: I tried this `if post.post_tag:
    post.post_tag = None

else:
    post.post_tag = request.user` it is stuck at the `else statement` and when I check the admin view, I can see nothing has been assigned. Do I need to save ?

Comment: Yes, the `post` object needs to be saved if you change any of its attributes and want to commit that to the db.

Answer (score 0):

```
class Question(models.Model):
webregister = models.ForeignKey(Webregister, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
que = models.CharField(max_length=255,null=True, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.pk)


orgs = Question.objects.filter(webregister=module,que__isnull=True)
orgs.delete()
```

Comment: Please consider to add some word comment